# Cloud Sql Migration Failure from External Datasource

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

I am trying to create a read-only slave on an existing database. I managed to export my data, put it into a bucket, remove all the lines with DEFINER clause and successfully create a replica database.

Here is my dump command-

```
mysqldump --databases alphadb -h localhost -u root -p \
--hex-blob --skip-triggers --set-gtid-purged=OFF  \
--default-character-set=utf8mb4 > dump.sql
```

And here is the command I use to remove the DEFINER clauses -

```
cat dump.sql | sed '/DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`/d'
```

The problem is shortly thereafter, I get errors in my log:

[image]

All the answers I found to deal with this 1062 Duplicate Key error suggested the following:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
START SLAVE;
SELECT SLEEP(5);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

Examples of solutions:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/mysql-replication-error
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139257/mysql-replication-duplicate-entry-for-primary-key/139265

The problem is I get:

```
MySQL [alphadb]> stop slave;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I'm already root, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do next in order to resolve the error so replication can continue. Technically, I would even be happy to just truncate the ci_sessions table since it's not important to me, and reset the primary keys. This isn't possible because the  database is in `read-only` mode though (It's also not a great solution since the goal is to get replication to generally work)

My question is what should I do next? Google's Cloud Sql doesn't support `SUPER` privilege but `STOP SLAVE` and `START SLAVE` require the SUPER privilege.

**EDIT:**
From the 2nd link in kurtisvg's reply I was able to determine that I was missing some of the recommended flags. The solution was to use those flags, in the following format

```
mysqldump \
    -h [MASTER_IP] -P [MASTER_PORT] -u [USERNAME] -p \
    --databases [DBS]  \
    --hex-blob  --skip-triggers  --master-data=1  \
    --order-by-primary --no-autocommit \
    --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --ignore-table [VIEW] \
    --single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=on
```

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external
Lastly, in case anyone from Google sees this, your error log (outside of offering impossible advice) also offers the wrong command. In the above screenshot, the log suggests `SLAVE START` but the correct command is `START SLAVE`

I was really looking forward to migrating my company off its existing infrastructure and onto GCP, but unfortunately there is no path towards doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud SQL has step by step instructions for how to do this. Check the following pages from the docs:

- [Configuring external replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-replica)
- [Replicating from external server](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external)

Comment: From the 2nd link I was able to determine that I was missing some flags during the `mysqldump` command. After adding those flags, my migration well smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I Was dealing with the same issue while trying out the same scenario.
I Used the guide from the second link from the beginning and still got the duplicate entry errors all the time.

Only thing that eventually worked out for me was to drop the '--single-transaction' parameter from the export process. This is how my export script ended looking like:

```
mysqldump \
    -h 192.168.1.8 -P 3306 -u root -p \
    --databases db1 db2 db3 db4 \
    --hex-blob  --skip-triggers  --master-data=1  \
    --order-by-primary --no-autocommit \
    --default-character-set=utf8mb4 \
    --set-gtid-purged=on >mysqldump.sql
sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' -i mysqldump.sql
grep DEFINER mysqldump.sql
gzip mysqldump.sql
gsutil cp mysqldump.sql.gz gs://my-gs-storage/mysqldump-new.sql.gz
```